# Rxj error with merge operator

Tags: rxjs

I am on "rxjs": "^6.2.1".

Based on rxjs documentation of merge operator
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-docs/blob/master/src/operator-docs/combination/merge.ts.

I am trying to merge two observable of same return type.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
public metricsData$: Observable<Map<string, MetricState>>;
public statisticsList$: Observable<Map<string, MetricState>>;

//I am trying to merge both the streams.
const example = this.metricsData$.pipe(merge(this.statisticsList$));

I am getting below mentioned error:
```

Argument of type 'Observable>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
  Type 'Observable>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.

I am getting same error if i run the official example :

```
const first = interval(2500);

//emit every 1 second
const second = interval(1000);

//used as instance method
const example1 = first.pipe(merge(second));
```

The error:
Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
  Type 'Observable' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.

Can I get some help?

Comment: `first.pipe(f => merge(f, second))` but `merge(first, second)` is simpler.

Comment: @cartant worked